# Как с эмитировать нажатие клавиш cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell

Запускаю программа средствами bat'ника, на каком то этапе она просит ввести yes, а потом определённый текст. Как мне заранее с эмитировать этот ввод средствами bat

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну не дубликат же.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, там полноценное эмулирование нажатий клавиш, а тут надо подать букву на stdin консольной программы. Совершенно разные задачи и решения.

Comment: @Qwertiy а где тут указано что программа консольная?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ты часто в неконсольных вводил `yes` с клавиатуры?

Comment: @Qwertiy тут и про клавиатуру ничего нет. Я так понял, там диалог с двумя кнопками...

Comment: @Qwertiy видимо, это был критический провал телепатии

Comment: _"она просит ввести yes"_ - не нажать кнопку, не нажать Enter, а именно ввести `yes`. И теги cmd и powershell.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo smth >file.txt
pause File file.txt was created
echo y | del /p file.txt
pause File file.txt was deleted
```